# BlueSnap marketplace - will my vendor get paid?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, marketplace, bluesnap

I started selling through the marketplace in BlueSnap - I sell subscriptions, and I created vendor accounts in BlueSnap for my promoters who sell for me.

I basically created the vendor accounts with just the promoter's name, email and country:

```
{ 
    "email": "mark.cooper@gmail.com", 
    "country": "US",
    "firstName": "Mark",
    "lastName": "Cooper"

}
```

I was told that's it - and that I can sell with those vendor accounts. I sold for a few weeks and I got my share of the payment for the subscriptions - but my vendors didn't.

I want to sort it out, do you have any idea why this happened, how can I fix it for the future – and what I can do to get them paid for the past sales?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're describing is caused by missing details for that vendor. BlueSnap allows you to sell with an incomplete vendor, because sometimes getting the full details can take a while. However, only when the details are present and approved, the vendor can be paid. You don't have to worry about any back payments - they will be paid once the vendor is approved.

After you created your vendor with the details you described, you would have received a response with the vendor ID - let's say it's 407416 for this example. If you send a GET request to https://ws.bluesnap.com/services/2/vendors/407416, you may get something like:

```
{
   "vendorId": "407416",
   "email": "mark.cooper@gmail.com",
   "name": "Default Vendor",
   "firstName": "Mark",
   "lastName": "Cooper",
   "country": "us",
   "defaultPayoutCurrency": "USD",
   "frequency": "MONTHLY",
   "delay": "7",
   "payoutInfo": {
      "payoutType": "NONE",
      "baseCurrency": "USD",
      "minimalPayoutAmount": "35",
      "country": "us",
      "intermediaryBankInfo": null
   },
   "vendor-agreement": {
      "commissionPercent": "0",
      "accountStatus": "ACTIVE",
      "recurringCommission": "Y"
   },
   "verification": {
      "payoutStatus": "Incomplete",
      "processingStatus": "Active",
      "missingItems": [
         "vendor.phone",
         "vendor.address",
         "vendor.city",
         "vendor.zip",
         "vendor.principal.firstName",
         "vendor.principal.lastName",
         "vendor.principal.address",
         "vendor.principal.city",
         "vendor.principal.country",
         "vendor.principal.zip",
         "vendor.principal.dob",
         "vendor.principal.personalIdentificationNumber",
         "vendor.principal.email",
         "vendor.payout.info.payoutType",
         "vendor.payout.info.baseCurrency",
         "vendor.payout.info.nameOnAccount",
         "vendor.payout.info.bankAccountType",
         "vendor.payout.info.bankAccountClass",
         "vendor.payout.info.bankName",
         "vendor.payout.info.bankId",
         "vendor.payout.info.country",
         "vendor.payout.info.city",
         "vendor.payout.info.address",
         "vendor.payout.info.zip",
         "vendor.payout.info.bankAccountId"
      ]
   }
}
```

The part to notice is the verification container. In it, you can see a few things:

- the payout status is incomplete - that means your vendor will not get paid.
- the processing status is Active - that means that you can continue selling with this vendor - and BlueSnap will hold their payout for them until they are approved.
- most importantly, the missing items - these are the fields you need to add before you can get the vendor to be sent to approval.

In this example, you need to update the vendor with all the missing fields. You can send a PUT call to https://ws.bluesnap.com/services/2/407416 with the payload (I indented the parts I added):

```
{
   "vendorId": "407416",
   "email": "mark.cooper@gmail.com",
   "name": "Default Vendor",
   "firstName": "Mark",
   "lastName": "Cooper",
   "country": "us",
      "phone": "888438829",
      "address": "addedthis street 1",
      "zip": "36662",
      "city": "Detroit",
   "defaultPayoutCurrency": "USD",
   "frequency": "MONTHLY",
   "delay": "7",
     "vendorPrincipal": {
        "firstName": "Mark",
        "lastName": "Cooper",
        "address": "another street 23",
        "city": "Detroit",
        "zip": "3773",
        "country": "US",
        "dob": "12/12/1980",
        "personalIdentificationNumber": "47737299292229",
        "email": "mark.cooper@gmail.com"
     },
   "payoutInfo": {
          "payoutType": "ACH",
      "baseCurrency": "USD",
          "nameOnAccount": "Mark Cooper",
          "bankAccountType": "CHECKING",
          "bankAccountClass": "PERSONAL",
          "bankName": "First Bank of Newton",
          "bankId": "12234",
          "country": "US",
          "state": "KS",
          "city": "Newton",
          "address": "128 E Broadway St",
          "zip": "67114",
          "bankAccountId": "36628822",
      "minimalPayoutAmount": "35",
      "country": "us",
      "intermediaryBankInfo": null
   },
   "vendorAgreement": {
         "commissionPercent": "20",
      "accountStatus": "ACTIVE",
      "recurringCommission": "Y"
   }
}
```

The update vendor WS will validate the input and comment if any of it has any issues. Once you add the details in successfully, another GET call will show no missing items - and the payout status should move to pending. This means that BlueSnap is reviewing the vendor.

You can check up on the process with BlueSnap merchant support - or just subscribe in the control panel for a "VENDOR STATUS" type IPN, to get a warning that any vendor is approved. As part of the review process, the vendor's previous payouts will also be released in the next payout.

Assuming nothing else changes, you won't need to go through this update/review process again.